# Regarding Azure table design

Tags: azure, logging, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am working as freelancer and right now working on one of my game and trying to use Azure table service to log my user moves in Azure tables.
The game is based on Cards.

The flow is like this:

Many users(UserId) will be playing on a table(TableId). Each game on the table will have a unique GameId. In each game there could be multiple deals with Unique DealId.
There can be multiple deals on the same table with same gameId. Also each user will have same DealId in a single game.

Winner is decided after multiple chances of a player.

Problem:

I can make TableId as PartitionKey and but I am not sure what to chose for RowKey because combination of TableId and RowKey (GameId/UserId/DealId) should be unique in the table. 
I can have entries like:

TableId GameId DealId UserId timestamp
1            201      300    12345  
1            201      300    12567

May be what I can do is to create 4 Azure tables like below but I am doing a lot of duplication; also I would not be able to fire a a point query as mentioned here at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/#guidelines-for-table-design

GameLogsByTableId  -- this will have TableId as PartitionKey and GUID as RowKey
GameLogsByGameId -- this will have GameId as PartitionKey and GUID as RowKey
GameLogsByUserId -- this will have UserId as PartitionKey and GUID as RowKey
GameLogsByDealId -- this will have DealId as PartitionKey and GUID as RowKey

Thoughts please?

Format of TableId,GameId,DealId and UserId is long.

I would like to query data such that

1. Get me all the logs from a TableId.
2. Get me all the logs from a TableId and in a particular game(GameId)
3. Get me all the logs of a user(userid) in this game(GameId)
4. Get me all the logs of a user in a deal(dealId)
5. Get me all the logs from a table on a date; similarly for a user,game and deal

Comment: @MichaelB I am not sure if you have read my question or not but actually I read the documentation and based on that I came up with a solution. Wanted to know if this is good or bad. I do not expect someone to do my home work :-)

Comment: Can you update your question by answering the following questions: 1) How are you planning on querying the data? 2) What is the format of your TableId, GameId, DealId, and UserId fields? Looking at your example, I am guessing it is numerical but wanted to confirm. 3) When querying, will there be some scenarios where you would be interested in getting the latest values directly? 4) When querying, will you be looking to directly find the information based on certain set of parameters e.g. find record of a combination of TableId and GameId?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my knowledge so far on Azure Tables, I believe you're on right track.

However there are certain things I would like to mention:

**You could use a single table for storing all data**

You don't really need to use separate tables for storing each kind of data though this approach logically separates the data nicely. If you want, you could possibly store them in a single table. If you go with single table, since these ids (Game, Table, User, and Deal) are numbers what I would recommend is to prefix the value appropriately so that you can nicely identify them. For example, when specifying PartitionKey denoting a Game Id, you can prefix the value with `G|` so that you know it's the Game Id e.g. `G|101`.

**Pre-pad your Id values with `0` to make them equal length string**
You mentioned that your id values are `long`. However the `PartitionKey` value is of `string` type. I would recommend prepadding the values so that they are of equal length. For example, when storing Game Id as PartitionKey instead of storing them as `1`, `2`, `103` etc. store them as `00000000001`, `00000000002`, `00000000103`. This way when you list all Ids, they will be sorted in proper order. Without prepadding, you will get the results as 1, 10, 11, 12....19, 20.

**You will loose transaction support**

Since you're using multiple tables (or even single table with different PartitionKeys), you will not be able to use `Entity Batch Transactions` available in Azure Tables and all the inserts need to be done as atomic operations. Since each operation is a network call and can possibly fail, you may want to do that through an idempotent background process which will keep on trying inserting the data into multiple tables till the time it succeeds.

**Instead of Guid for `RowKey`, I suggest you create a composite `RowKey` based on other values**

This is more applicable for update scenario. Since an update requires both `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`, I would recommend using a `RowKey` which is created as a composition of other values. For example, if you're using `TableId` as PartitionKey for `GameLogsByTableId`, I would suggest creating a `RowKey` using other values e.g. `U|[UserId]|D|[DealId]|G|[GameId]`. This way, when you get a record to update, you automatically know how to create a `RowKey` instead of fetching the data first from the table.

**Partition Scans**

I looked at your querying requirements and almost all of them would result in `Partition Scans`. To avoid that, I would suggest keeping even more duplicate copies of the data. For example, consider #3 and #4 in your querying requirements. In this case, you will need to scan the entire partition for a user to find information about a Game Id and Deal Id. So please be prepared for the scenario where table service returns you nothing but continuation tokens.

Comment: Thanks for taking time on this one. I would consider these points while designing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, unless you have absolutely massive data requirements, I would not use table storage for this. It will make your job much harder than using an SQL database; you can use any index you like, have relational integrity, and so much more. The only thing in favour of ATS is that it's cheap for large data.